# C# UI multiple KeyDown Events ?? windows form application

Tags: c#, events, user-interface, key

I am working on an mp3 player with minimal UI, in C# using windowsForm app.

currently I have methods for open play and pause a song.

As I want the UI minimal,  I only display the fileName of the playing song.

Now the problem is when I am trying to assign a KeyDown Event for each method.

As all in my form I can select and map a KeyPress Event to is the Empty form, but it can only hold 1 KeyDown event, which now means I can only get 1 method to run..

How can I solve this ?

I assume I could use KeyPress and KeyUp events for my other 2 methods to run,   but I suppose theres a more clever solution ?

part of my code:  in this example,  OpenFile  works... but Play doesnt work at the same time,  because I havent assigned any EventHandler for it, I guess.  But as I dont want any button in the UI.,,  What can I then do ??

I dont want a traditional shortcut command either. like ctrl + key.

```
private void o(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.O)
            {
                openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            }
        }

        private void p(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.P)
            {
                player.Play();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply

```
private void o(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.O)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }

        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.P)
        {
            player.Play();
        }
    }
```

you may want to define only one event-handler, but you can check for several keys pressed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally put it into a case statement and into a single method/function. This way you can expand without a web of if/thens.

```
private void o(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
switch (e.KeyCode) {
    case Keys.O: 
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        break;
    case Keys.P:
        player.Play();
        break;
    default: 
        break;
  }
}
```